# Opening modal overlay before main overlay

Tags: jquery, cookies, overlay

I'm using jQuery Tools. What I want to do is this: Once a user clicks a text link, verify if a cookie exists; if it does not, open a modal overlay asking him to select a region; once he does, store it in a cookie and then open the main overlay.

If the cookie already exists, then directly open the main overlay.

What I have so far is this:

```
$(function() {

// if the function argument is given to overlay,
// it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
$("a[rel]").live('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var el = $(this);
    var target = el.attr('rel');
    $(target).appendTo('body');

    $(this).overlay({
    mask: {color:'black'},
    effect: 'apple',
    api: true,

    onBeforeLoad: function() {

// grab wrapper element inside content
        var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

        // load the page specified in the trigger
        wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));

    },
    load:true,
    closeOnClick: false

     });
});
});
```

I know that at some point, I shoud have something like this:

```
        if ($.cookie('myRegion') == null){ 
            $("#selectRegion").overlay().load();
        }
```

But am not sure where it fits in. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just to confirm, make sure you are loading [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

This might seem like a simple solution, but basically it will check for the cookie, if it is not there then create the dialog, and either close the dialog or save the selection depending on whether the background or the button was clicked.

Try something like this for your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.cookie("myRegion") == null){
        $("#modal-background").toggleClass("active");
        $("#modal-content").toggleClass("active");
    }

    $("#modal-background").click(function(){
        $("#modal-background").toggleClass("active");
        $("#modal-content").toggleClass("active");
    });
    $("#modal-save").click(function(){
        $.cookie("myRegion", $("region").val());
        $("#modal-background").toggleClass("active");
        $("#modal-content").toggleClass("active");
    });
});​
```

All the associated HTML and CSS can be found in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9HrwN/2/

Comment: Thanks, I adapted your code to fit my needs but this is working perfectly.

Comment: Ahh great to hear :) If you think it would be good to share with others, it wouldn't hurt to upvote and accept the answer :)